# SQL Developer error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to use SQL developer, but it won't connect using the proxy I specify in the preferences. I guess it's because of some kind of certificate error? Not sure. I'm getting the error:

No HTTP response received.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1591)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:187)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:181)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:975)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:123)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:516)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:454)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1096)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1123)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1107)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:405)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
    at oracle.ide.webbrowser.HttpPing$PingRunnable.run(HttpPing.java:109)
    at oracle.ide.webbrowser.ProxyOptions.doTask(ProxyOptions.java:522)
    at oracle.ide.webbrowser.HttpPing.ping(HttpPing.java:74)
    at oracle.ide.webbrowser.ProxySettingsPanel$5.run(ProxySettingsPanel.java:766)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:285)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:191)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:954)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:280)
    ... 21 more

Answer (score 3):

This most likely means that the web server you are connecting to by SSL uses a certificate issued by an unknown authority. You want to add the certificate to your keystore (on the client).

See this [article](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210) for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't install jdk yet. I recommand you if you use sql developer 1.5.1, you should use jdk 1.5.

Answer (score -2):

One of the first rules of debugging errors:  Google the error message you're getting, in quotes, like this: "unable to find valid certification path to".  When I did this, I found lots of useful information that is probably relevant to you.

Comment: While this is true, I think that goes for LOTS of SO questions. One of the aims of SO is to become the site which people get when they google the errors.